# Why does the sandalwood tree produce a fragrant oil?

Tags: evolution, biochemistry, botany

Why do sandal trees produce fragrant oil? Is there any purpose for it? Is it to make it unpalatable for other herbivorous animals? If so, why do humans find the fragrance pleasing?

Comment: Probably the same reasons as lavender, sage, vanilla, lemontree, jasmin, thyme, and other plants used for extracts. They generally protects the plant and aromatic effect is a coincidental side effect for our species. Catnip is an odd example of aromatic side fx.